# Отправление при помощи curl post запроса с данными в xml

Tags: php, xml, post, curl

Есть некий XML и ссылка на сторонний сервис:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/';
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
            <Request>
              <Language>ru</Language>
            </Request>';
```

Если отправить xml через форму:

```
<form method="post" action="https://example.com/">
  <textarea name="Request"><?php echo $xml; ?></textarea>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

То сервер возвращает данные на основе отправленных в xml.
Пытаюсь тоже самое сделать с помощью curl:

```
function sendXmlOverPost($url, $xml) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $result;
}
print_r(sendXmlOverPost($url, $xml));
```

Возвращается ошибка, System error!

Answer (score -1):

```
function sendXmlOverPost($url, $xml) {
  $xml['Request'] = $xml;  // <<<<< Всё внимание сюда, и на форму в html =) 
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $result;
}
$url = 'https://example.com/';
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><Request><Language>ru</Language></Request>';
print_r(sendXmlOverPost($url, $xml));
```

Comment: Спасибо, но сейчас такая ошибка "Warning: Illegal string offset 'Request' "

$xmlArr = array('Request' => $xml); - тоже не решил проблему

Comment: Вы пытаетесь запросы к API делать?

Comment: отправляет успешно, но ошибка есть Warning: Illegal string offset 'Request'

Comment: @Леха
Удивительно правда? особенно если просто бездумно скопировать код не понимая как он работает :) можете заметить `$xml['Request'] = $xml;` на `$xml2['Request'] = $xml;` и далее по коду `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml2);` ну или понять на что оно ругается и сделать правильно :)

Comment: пробовал, как только так делаю сразу 1С пишет ошибку, что xml не верен, а как пишу вот так $xml['Request'] = $xml; почему то работает. но в коде ошибка падает. Вообще пробовал по разному, но работает только вот так $xml['Request'] = $xml; почему, не понятно

Comment: Ну я выше уже написал - если просто бездумно скопировать код из сети, совершенно не понимая что и для чего он делает - вполне логично что это не заработает так как вам хотелось :) код выше написан для конкретной проблемы, которая была у автора вопроса :) вы вполне резонно заметили что в коде есть ошибка(на некоторых версиях пхп эта ошибка не критична) - я в свою очередь написал как исправить эту ошибку :) ошибку в самом коде, а не в алгоритме который вероятнее всего вам просто не подходит :) почему бы не задать свой вопрос, вместо попыток использовать ответ от чужого вопроса?